# Memory-efficient BERT Text Embedding for Large Dataset Preprocessing in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, embedding

I'm working with a dataset containing approximately 920,614 rows and multiple columns, including "orig_item_title," "sub_item_title," "is_brand_same," and "is_flavor_same." The goal is to build a model that predicts the similarity or relevance of items, specifically whether a substitute item is similar to the original item. I'm implementing a learning-to-rank (LTR) framework, incorporating features such as brand and flavor matching along with embeddings from the BERT encoder for text columns.

Here's the code snippet for preprocessing the features and creating a TensorFlow dataset:

```
from transformer import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel
import tensorflow as tf

#load a pre-trained BERT model and tokenizer
 model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
 tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
 bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)  # Embedding size is 768
    
# Define a function for BERT encoding
def bert_encoder(text_column):
    input_ids = tokenizer(text_column, return_tensors="tf", truncation=True, padding=True)["input_ids"]
    outputs = bert_model(input_ids)
    pooled_output = outputs.pooler_output
    return pooled_output

def preprocess_features(df):
    # Extract features and labels
    text_columns = ["orig_item_title", "sub_item_title"]
    numerical_columns = ["is_brand_same",  'is_flavor_same']
    label_column = "acc_rate"

    features = {
        "orig_item_title": df["orig_item_title"],
        "sub_item_title": df["sub_item_title"],
       "is_brand_same": df["is_brand_same"],
       'is_flavor_same': df['is_flavor_same'],
    }

    for col in text_columns:
        features[col] = bert_encoder(df[col].tolist())  

    # Numerical columns
    numerical_features = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(col) for col in numerical_columns]
    features.update({col: df[col] for col in numerical_columns})

    return features, df[label_column]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(preprocess_features(df))
```

However, I'm encountering an Out-of-Memory (OOM) error when executing the preprocessing as it is processing a tensor of shape [920614,55,768]. I'm seeking advice on reducing the embedding dimension, possibly to 256 or 128, and exploring alternative approaches to make the preprocessing successful without exhausting memory. Any suggestions or code guidance would be really helpful.

Also, could someone provide assistance with coding the model, including the integration of BERT layer embeddings for text features, concatenation with numerical features, and the inclusion of a neural network layer with sigmoid predictions in the output layer?

Thank you.